# GIT - how to put release note to a TAG

Tags: git, git-tag

I used shell command:

```
git tag -a drugiTag -m "drugi message"
```

to create tag. How to add release notes to this tag?

pierwszyTag was already there and in GET REST response looks like this:
[image: pierwszyTag it's a TAG which was already there]

drugiTag is my new tag created using command in CMD. How to add RELEASE: tag_name and description like in pierwszyTag:
[image: drugiTag new]

Comment: Using options [`-m` or `-F`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt--mltmsggt). What is your problem with them?

Comment: What command should I use to add release notes to this TAG.
Using GitLab GUI it's easy but I want to write a script in CMD which pull TAG's from one repo and push to another with release notes

Comment: `git tag -a drugiTag -m "line 1" -m "line 3" -m "line 5"` or `git tag -a drugiTag -F file-with-message` or `echo "long message" | git tag -a drugiTag -F-`

Comment: Git does not do "release notes". It has tags, and tags can have messages. That you want to use a tag message to put release notes into is a convention that isn't Git-related. If you consider that, what is your actual question? "How to get a message from a Git tag using the command line"?

Comment: Maybe it can be done using GitLab API - REST method POST?

Answer (score 1):

Found this in a github community post. Hope it helps.

> Since the “Releases” feature is part of GitHub and not git itself, no,
> there isn’t a way to set the release notes using the git command-line
> tool.

https://github.community/t/add-release-notes-to-git-remote-tag-from-command-line/1932